# Cannot connect to a MySql Server using MySql Workbench with no apparent reason

Tags: sql, debian, mysql

I can't connect via TCP/IP to the MySQL server.

The server is installed in a Debian Linux and there's a PostGreSQL server running at the same time. (which is working fine and has tcp/ip connection btw)

But everytime I try to remotely connect to the MYSQL server I get the following:

```
Connecting to MySQL server 172.29.85.188...
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.29.70.25' (using password: YES)
```

Am I missing something here? I can log in fine if I run a SSH connection to the server. I also DID change the mysql.conf file to remove the BLINDIP setting.

btw: I tried also using the line

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

I get a reply:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And still no remote access. (I'm pretty sure the 0 rows affected has something to do with it)

Comment: The default installation often only add privileges for root@localhost and there's usually a parameter called `bind-address` set to localhost as well. Have you checked this?

Comment: -1, the reason is very obvious (remote connect vs ssh)

Comment: The bind-address has been fixed already. I still need to grant privileges? How?

Comment: Check the ACL, if remote connect is direct from your pc, you remote address is different.

Comment: ACL? Could you be more specific? There's no mention of ACL on the MYSQL manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was reformating the server. 
Not the best answer, but due to time constrains I couldn't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

0 rows affected is normal for a grant.

Did you try doing FLUSH PRIVILEGES after running your grant?

-- EDIT --

I just noticed the date on this question.  I'm guessing this is already fixed :)

Maybe this will help someone else...

Comment: Yes I did. 
I couldn't find any help to I simply re formatted the server machine.